# Adobe Content Server with Zen Cart

Tags: drm, zen-cart

Has anyone (or does anyone) have any insight on integrating Adobe Content Server (DRM) with Zen Cart as a working solution?

I'm looking to build a solution for delivering DRM documents through a Zen Cart storefront, and would welcome any insight on it from someone who has walked the walk.

We have the Adobe Content Server now installed, and the sample store code is delivering the ePub files.

I am familiar with the BOOKS.XML file, which contains the catalog of books for the distributor. The quandry is getting Zen Cart configured to be able to place the link for the .acms file after the order is processed (payment is receieved, etc), and store the information in the customer account for future access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you deploy a content server and add a distributor (for say your zen cart book store), it releases store config.xml and catalog.xml for your store.

catalog.xml contains data of the files which are allowed to your store by content server admin.

I am having trouble posting xml fiel here.

All you need to do is parse the Catalog.xml. It has all the values like:

- Title
- Author
- Publisher
- Download Link
- Cover Image Link

And many more info like permissions, resolution, type etc.

If you go to evaluate the content server, they will provide you with sample store built in php in which they show the parsed sample catalog.xml into a full working store.

All you

Comment: Thank you for the reply - I'll look into the catalog.xml file. Then, it would simply be a matter of mapping the download link in the shopping cart (customer account detail screen) to the path of the file in the XML outputted by the content server?

Comment: Would you know if the Zen Cart must reside on the same server as the Content Server, or can it be on another server apart from the Content Server?

Comment: Adobe Content server i sjust a software where you publish your ebooks  and alot the distribution services. It can even be created on a web connected standalone PC(configuration required is good). Though Zen cart is required at your webstore/website end.